# Timing out in a shell script

Tags: shell, signals, timeout

I have a **shell script** that's **reading from standard input**. In rare circumstances, there will be no one ready to provide input, and the script must **time out**. In case of timeout, the script must execute some cleanup code. What's the best way to do that?

This script must be **very portable**, including to 20th century unix systems without a C compiler and to embedded devices running busybox, so Perl, bash, any compiled language, and even the full POSIX.2 can't be relied on. In particular, `$PPID`, `read -t` and perfectly POSIX-compliant traps are not available. Writing to a temporary file is also excluded; the script might run even if all filesystems are mounted read-only.

Just to make things more difficult, I also want the script to be reasonably **fast** when it doesn't time out. In particular, I also use the script in Windows (mainly in Cygwin), where fork and exec are particularly low, so I want to keep their use to a minimum.

In a nutshell, I have

```
trap cleanup 1 2 3 15
foo=`cat`
```

and I want to add a timeout. I can't replace `cat` with the `read` built-in. In case of timeout, I want to execute the `cleanup` function.

---

Background: this script is guessing the encoding of the terminal by printing some 8-bit characters and comparing the cursor position before and after. The beginning of the script tests that stdout is connected to a supported terminal, but sometimes the environment is lying (e.g. [`plink` sets `TERM=xterm` even if it's called with `TERM=dumb`](http://osdir.com/ml/emacs.tramp/2003-09/msg00011.html)). The relevant part of the script looks like this:

```
text='Éé'  # UTF-8; shows up as ÃÃ© on a latin1 terminal
csi='␛['; dsr_cpr="${csi}6n"; dsr_ok="${csi}5n"  # ␛ is an escape character
stty_save=`stty -g`
cleanup () { stty "$stty_save"; }
trap 'cleanup; exit 120' 0 1 2 3 15     # cleanup code
stty eol 0 eof n -echo                # Input will end with `0n`
# echo-n is a function that outputs its argument without a newline
echo-n "$dsr_cpr$dsr_ok"              # Ask the terminal to report the cursor position
initial_report=`tr -dc \;0123456789`  # Expect ␛[42;10R␛[0n for y=42,x=10
echo-n "$text$dsr_cpr$dsr_ok"
final_report=`tr -dc \;0123456789`
cleanup
# Compute and return initial_x - final_x
```

How can I modify the script so that if `tr` hasn't read any input after 2 seconds, it is killed and the script executes the `cleanup` function?

Comment: See also [How to introduce timeout for shell scripting?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43340) for less portable solutions

Answer (score 37, accepted):

What about this:

```
foo=`{ { cat 1>&3; kill 0; } | { sleep 2; kill 0; } } 3>&1`
```

That is: run the output-producing command and `sleep` in the same process group, a process group just for them. Whichever command returns first kills the whole process group.

Would anyone wonder: Yes, the pipe is not used; it's bypassed using the redirections. The sole purpose of it is to have the shell run the two process in the same process group.

---

As Gilles pointed out in his comment, this won't work in a shell script because the script process would be killed along with the two subprocesses.

One way¹ to force a command to run in a separate process group is to start a new interactive shell:

```
#!/bin/sh
foo=`sh -ic '{ cat 1>&3; kill 0; } | { sleep 2; kill 0; }' 3>&1 2>/dev/null`
[ -n "$foo" ] && echo got: "$foo" || echo timeouted
```

But there might be caveats with this (e.g. when stdin is not a tty?). The stderr redirection is there to get rid of the "Terminated" message when the interactive shell is killed.

Tested with `zsh`,`bash` and `dash`. But what about oldies?

[B98](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/148008/b98) suggests the following change, working on Mac OS X, with GNU bash 3.2.57, or Linux with dash:

```
foo=`sh -ic 'exec 3>&1 2>/dev/null; { cat 1>&3; kill 0; } | { sleep 2; kill 0; }'`
```

–
<sup>1. other than `setsid` which appears to be non-standard.</sup>

Comment: I quite like this, I hadn't thought of using a process group that way. It's pretty simple and there's no race condition. I need to test it for portability some more, but this looks like a winner.

Comment: Unfortunately, this fails spectacularly as soon as I put this in a script: the pipeline in the command substitution does not run in its own process group, and `kill 0` ends up killing the script's caller as well. Is there a portable way to force the pipeline into its own process group?

Comment: @Gilles: Eek! couldn't find a way to `setprgp()` without `setsid` for now :-(

Comment: @Gilles: See my edit. Not pretty and I can't tell about portability.

Comment: I really like the trick, so I'm awarding the bounty. It seems to work on Linux, I haven't had time to test it on other systems yet.

Comment: Is there an easy way to adapt this method such that the output-producing command outputs to the invoking terminal in real-time? In the above example, output is only visible after timeout/completion via the variable whose value was set to the output of the double-program-group magic.

Comment: @Zac: Don't tell me you also need to run commands on 20th century systems? You can just remove the variable assignation if you don't want to collect the output.

Comment: Sure, but if I run `{ { echo boo; kill 0; } | { sleep 2; kill 0; } } 3>&1`, I don't see "boo" printed to stdout.

Comment: @Zac: You forgot the `1>&3` redirection after the echo.

Comment: D'oh! Also, for brevity's sake, you can reverse the ordering of the two internal program groups, and then you don't have to do any redirection. Gorgeous solution, btw.

Comment: @Zac: It's not possible to reverse the ordering in the original case, because only the first process get access to stdin.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work on OSX, probably their bash is too old: `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Answer (score 6):

```
me=$$
(sleep 2; kill $me >/dev/null 2>&1) & nuker=$!
# do whatever
kill $nuker >/dev/null 2>&1
```

You're already trapping 15 (the numeric version of `SIGTERM`, which is what `kill` sends unless told otherwise), so you should already be good to go.  That said, if you are looking at pre-POSIX, be aware that shell functions may not exist either (they came from System V's shell).

Comment: It's not that simple. If you trap the signal, many shells (dash, bash, pdksh, zsh… probably all except ATT ksh) ignore it while they're waiting for `cat` to exit. I've already experimented a little but not found anything I'm satisfied with so far.

Comment: On portability: thankfully I have functions everywhere. I'm not sure about `$!`, I think some of those machines I use rarely don't have job control, is `$!` universally available?

Comment: @Gilles: Hm, yeh.  I recall some truly hideous and `bash`-specific stuff I did once involving abuse of `-o monitor`.  I was thinking in terms of truly ancient shells when I wrote that (it worked in v7).  That said, I think you can do either of two other things: (1) background "whatever" and `wait $!`, or (2) also send `SIGCLD`/`SIGCHLD`... but on old enough machines the latter is either nonexistent or nonportable (the former is System III/V, the latter BSD, and V7 had neither).

Comment: @Gilles: `$!` goes back to V7 at least, and certainly predates a `sh`-like that knew anything about job control (in fact, for a long time `/bin/sh` on BSD didn't do job control; you *had* to run `csh` to get it — but `$!` was there).

Comment: I can't background “whatever”, I need its output. Thanks for the info about `$!`.

Answer (score 5):

Although coretuils as of version 7.0 includes a timeout command you've mentioned some environments that won't have it. Fortunately [pixelbeat.org](http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/) has a timeout script written `sh`.

I've used it before on several occasions and it works very well.

http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/timeout (**Note:** The script below has been slightly modified from the one on pixelbeat.org, see the comments below this answer.)

```
#!/bin/sh

# Execute a command with a timeout

# Author:
#    http://www.pixelbeat.org/
# Notes:
#    Note there is a timeout command packaged with coreutils since v7.0
#    If the timeout occurs the exit status is 124.
#    There is an asynchronous (and buggy) equivalent of this
#    script packaged with bash (under /usr/share/doc/ in my distro),
#    which I only noticed after writing this.
#    I noticed later again that there is a C equivalent of this packaged
#    with satan by Wietse Venema, and copied to forensics by Dan Farmer.
# Changes:
#    V1.0, Nov  3 2006, Initial release
#    V1.1, Nov 20 2007, Brad Greenlee <brad@footle.org>
#                       Make more portable by using the 'CHLD'
#                       signal spec rather than 17.
#    V1.3, Oct 29 2009, Ján Sáreník <jasan@x31.com>
#                       Even though this runs under dash,ksh etc.
#                       it doesn't actually timeout. So enforce bash for now.
#                       Also change exit on timeout from 128 to 124
#                       to match coreutils.
#    V2.0, Oct 30 2009, Ján Sáreník <jasan@x31.com>
#                       Rewritten to cover compatibility with other
#                       Bourne shell implementations (pdksh, dash)

if [ "$#" -lt "2" ]; then
    echo "Usage:   `basename $0` timeout_in_seconds command" >&2
    echo "Example: `basename $0` 2 sleep 3 || echo timeout" >&2
    exit 1
fi

cleanup()
{
    trap - ALRM               #reset handler to default
    kill -ALRM $a 2>/dev/null #stop timer subshell if running
    kill $! 2>/dev/null &&    #kill last job
      exit 124                #exit with 124 if it was running
}

watchit()
{
    trap "cleanup" ALRM
    sleep $1& wait
    kill -ALRM $$
}

watchit $1& a=$!         #start the timeout
shift                    #first param was timeout for sleep
trap "cleanup" ALRM INT  #cleanup after timeout
"$@" < /dev/tty & wait $!; RET=$?    #start the job wait for it and save its return value
kill -ALRM $a            #send ALRM signal to watchit
wait $a                  #wait for watchit to finish cleanup
exit $RET                #return the value
```

Comment: It seems that this does not allow to retrieve the output of the command. See "I can't background “whatever“" comment by Gilles in the other answer.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I've modified the script (so it won't match the one on pixelbeat anymore) to redirect /dev/stdin into the command. It seems to work in my testing.

Comment: This doesn't work to have the command read from standard input, except (oddly) in bash. `</dev/stdin` is a no-op. `</dev/tty` would enable it to read from the terminal, which is good enough for my use case.

Comment: @Giles: cool, I'll make that update.

Comment: This can't work without considerably more effort: I need to retrieve the command's output, and I can't do that if the command is in the background.

Comment: Well, it wasn't my script. I was just hoping that it would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

What about (ab)use NC for this

Like;

```
   $ nc -l 0 2345 | cat &  # output come from here
   $ nc -w 5 0 2345   # input come from here and times out after 5 sec
```

Or rolled up into a single command line;

```
   $ foo=`nc -l 0 2222 | nc -w 5 0 2222`
```

The last version, although looking stange actually does work when I test it on a linux system -- my best guess is that it should work on any system, and if not a variation of output redirection may solve for portability.    benefit here is that no background processes are involved.

Comment: Not portable enough. I don't have `nc` on some old Unix boxen, nor on many embedded Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to run the pipeline in its own process group is to run `sh -c '....'` in a pseudo-terminal using the `script` command (which implicitly applies the `setsid` function).

```
#!/bin/sh
stty -echo -onlcr
# GNU script
foo=`script -q -c 'sh -c "{ cat 1>&3; kill 0; } | { sleep 5; kill 0; }" 3>&1 2>/dev/null' /dev/null`
# FreeBSD script
#foo=`script -q /dev/null sh -c '{ cat 1>&3; kill 0; } | { sleep 5; kill 0; }' 3>&1 2>/dev/null`
stty echo onlcr
echo "foo: $foo"


# alternative without: stty -echo -onlcr
# cr=`printf '\r'`
# foo=`script -q -c 'sh -c "{ { cat 1>&3; kill 0; } | { sleep 5; kill 0; } } 3>&1 2>/dev/null"' /dev/null | sed -e "s/${cr}$//" -ne 'p;N'`  # GNU
# foo=`script -q /dev/null sh -c '{ { cat 1>&3; kill 0; } | { sleep 5; kill 0; } } 3>&1 2>/dev/null' | sed -e "s/${cr}$//" -ne 'p;N'`  # FreeBSD
# echo "foo: $foo"
```

Comment: Not portable enough. I don't have `script` on some old Unix boxen, nor on many embedded Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18711 is very nice.

I wanted to achieve a similar outcome, but without having to explicitly invoke the shell again because I wanted to invoke existing shell functions.

Using bash, it is possible to do the following:

```
eval 'set -m ; ( ... ) ; '"$(set +o)"
```

So suppose I already have a shell function `f`:

```
f() { date ; kill 0 ; }

echo Before
eval 'set -m ; ( f ) ; '"$(set +o)"
echo After
```

Executing this I see:

```
$ sh /tmp/foo.sh
Before
Mon 14 Mar 2016 17:22:41 PDT
/tmp/foo.sh: line 4: 17763 Terminated: 15          ( f )
After
```

Answer (score -2):

```
timeout_handler () { echo Timeout. goodbye.;  exit 1; }
trap timeout_handler ALRM
( sleep 60; kill -ALRM $$ ) &
```

Comment: This doesn't work [for the same reason as geekausor's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10698/timing-out-in-a-shell-script/330419#comment14081_10699). I need to obtain the output of an external command, and the signal is ignored while this command is running.