# Jump out of a process when it get stuck

Tags: bash, scripting

I have written a loop to iterate all `.out` c binary file and copy their outputs into a text file (the output for every binary file is just a one line hash value, one line output for one program). Here is my code so far:

```
for j in {1..10}
do
    ./gcc-$j.out >> gcc-result.txt
done
```

Unfortunately, some binary files have some unknown issues and cannot be correctly executed (they got stuck and cannot proceed to the next program).

I am not going to fix those c code but I want my bash to automatically jump to executing the next program within a given timeout (say 10 secs), and also write "0" to the `gcc-result.txt`.

Thanks in advance if you have idea to solve this issue.

Comment: Does the "stuck" process need to be killed or can it just be ignored and left to run to completion?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it should be killed, and output "0" result file (occupy one line)

Comment: Isn't this an instance of the famed "Halting Problem"?

Comment: @BruceEdiger No. The spec quite clearly says that the code should skip a file if it takes more than "say 10 secs" to terminate. You don't need to know if it's going to halt or not: just whether it did halt within a time limit.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - thanks for the consideration.  "Say, 10 seconds" sounds like a very informal spec, and to my mind, a requirement conceived of without much thought. But, yes, that makes it not an instance of the Halting Problem.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601543/command-line-command-to-auto-kill-a-command-after-a-certain-amount-of-time

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the timeout command :

```
if timeout 10 ping google.fr > /dev/null
then
    echo "process successful"
else
    echo "process killed"
fi
```

shows `process killed`, and

```
if timeout 10 ls /usr/bin | wc -l > /dev/null
then
    echo "process successful"
else
    echo "process killed"
fi
```

shows `process successful`. Based on this, you could run each command using such an `if; then; else; fi`, redirect the standard output to a temporary file, and copy that temporary to the target file in the successful case, while generating the target file in the failure case.

[How can I kill a process and be sure the PID hasn't been reused](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/181028/100397) could be helpful in case you don't have timeout.

Answer (score 4):

You can certainly kill the child process after some execution time and append the text file you need with '0' from within your bash-script.
You may find [Bash script that kills a child process after a given timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161193/bash-script-that-kills-a-child-process-after-a-given-timeout) useful.