# Terminate python code without letting it finish if while loop condition is unmet in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have this so far. The issue is, if `pythoncode.py` started before `8*60*60` seconds, then it can still continue running beyond `8*60*60` seconds until it finishes and only then will it stop. I need it to terminate `pythoncode.py` at exactly (loosely, +- 1 second is not an issue) `8*60*60` seconds even if it is running.

```
#! /bin/bash
end=$((SECONDS+8*60*60))

while [ $SECONDS -lt $end ]; do
    python3 /Users/Name/Desktop/pythoncode.py
done
```

I'm a beginner so explaining what to do specifically with this example would be appreciated over  just a general answer. Thanks and happy new year.

Comment: Possibly related: [Automatically kill process if its runtime exceeds some predetermined value](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21542/automatically-kill-process-if-its-runtime-exceeds-some-predetermined-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your python script in the background and use sleep function as a timer :

```
#Execute the script in the background
python3 /Users/Name/Desktop/pythoncode.py & 
#Get its process id
pypid=$!
#Wait for the needed period in seconds
sleep "$end"
#Then force the process to be terminated
kill -9 $pypid
```

Comment: Would this accomplish the exact same thing? `timeout 8h sh -c 'while true; do python3 /Users/Name/Desktop/pythoncode.py; done'`

Comment: Yes same thing here if you do have timeout installed :)

Comment: /usr/bin/timeout is in the coreutils package, so most probably it's installed.