# Run a command for a specified time and then abort if time exceeds

Tags: linux, time, timeout

I want know how I can run a command for a specified time say, one minute and if it doesn't complete execution then I should be able to stop it.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Use `timeout`:

```
NAME
       timeout - run a command with a time limit

SYNOPSIS
       timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...
       timeout [OPTION]
```

(Just in case, if you don't have this command or if you need to be compatible with very very old shells and have several other utterly specific requirements… have a look at this [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10698/timing-out-in-a-shell-script) ;-))

Comment: Perfect, thanks for linking to that question. I didn't have timeout on my system but I do now. Just on a side note, is timeout bundled with the majority of linux distributions?

Comment: Pretty cool.  you can do something like this:  `for i in \`seq 0 3\`; do timeout 2 ethtool -p eth$i; done;` to blink LED's on NIC's

Comment: What a sexy command. Thanks for pointing it out, wasn't aware of it.

Comment: Example: `timeout 5s vi` will run the editor for 5 seconds and will send `SIGTERM`. You can use `h` and `d` for hours and days.

Answer (score 0):

### How to use `timeout` with redirection to a file

For the `cat` case [in this question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31210/114401) (emphasis added):

> How can I cat a large file for, lets say, 45 seconds and output it to the screen **or redirect to another file.**

If you ever need this:

```bash
cat /dev/ttyUSB0 > out.txt
```

...instead of just this:

```bash
cat /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Then `timeout` won't work:

```bash
# This *does* work!: timeout after 0.5 sec
timeout 0.5 cat /dev/ttyUSB0

# Does NOT work: try to redirect a response over serial to a file.
# Using `timeout` with redirection of stdout to a file does *not*
# seem to work!
timeout 0.5 cat /dev/ttyUSB0 > out.txt
```

So, the work-around that *does* work is to store the output into a variable first, using `timeout` on that part only, and then to write that to a file, like this:

```bash
response_str="$(timeout 0.5 cat /dev/ttyUSB0)"
printf "%s" "$response_str" > out.txt
```

### See also

1. My answer on Stack Overflow here: [All about redirection in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74001320/4561887)

Comment: Your answer is touching on the topic of timing things out, but only handles only an odd niche case. A neater solution would be to use `timeout` on a child shell: `timeout 0.5 sh -c 'cat /dev/xxx' >out` although I can't get the blocking behaviour that you describe to happen unless I redirect into or out of the device (or named pipe).