# How to cat a file for a certain number of seconds?

Tags: time, cat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run a command for a specified time and then abort if time exceeds](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23145/run-a-command-for-a-specified-time-and-then-abort-if-time-exceeds)

Looked all over and I can't find the answer...

Simple question: How can I cat a large file for, lets say, 45 seconds and output it to the screen or redirect to another file.

Thanks!

Comment: For the "or redirect to another file" part of the question, which the accepted answer does _not_ cover at all, see my answer here: [How to use `timeout` with redirection to a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/720853/114401).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try:

```
timeout 45 cat yourfile
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161193/bash-script-that-kills-a-child-process-after-a-given-timeout

Comment: timeout is cleaner and allows the duration option to be specified in seconds, minutes, hours, as well as the option to specify which signal to send. cleaner and more readable

Comment: timeout not available on MacOS, at least in bash 3

Comment: @AlexanderMills Install coreutils via Homebrew, use `gtimeout`.

Comment: I just added an answer to this here: [How to use `timeout` with redirection to a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/720853/114401), for those who also need to redirect the output to a file with `> file`.