# Is there a way to call a command with a set time limit and kill it when that time passes?

Tags: bash, shell-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run a command for a specified time and then abort if time exceeds](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23145/run-a-command-for-a-specified-time-and-then-abort-if-time-exceeds)

I was working on a continuos integration build script when a need for such a command arose. Basically put, I need to launch a command with a set time limit for it to run before it gets killed and all of the proceeding commands should immediately be run once this command launches the time -limited process in the background and not wait for it get to be killed. A sort of asynchronous concurency.

Here's what I imagine:

```
timelimited --limit=10 'somecommand --someoptions'
someothercommand //This gets launched immediately once 'timelimited' is done creating the background process
```

Comment: Have a look at [BashFAQ 68](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/068).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

BASH FAQ entry #68: ["How do I run a command, and have it abort (timeout) after N seconds?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/068)

> **FIRST** check whether the command you're running can be told to timeout directly. The methods described here are "hacky" workarounds to force a command to terminate after a certain time has elapsed. Configuring your command properly is *always* preferable to the alternatives below.
>
> If the command has no native support for stopping after a specified time, then the best alternatives are some external commands called [timeout](http://www.porcupine.org/forensics/tct.html) and [doalarm](http://pilcrow.madison.wi.us/). Some Linux distributions offer the tct version of `timeout` as a package. There is also a GNU version of timeout, included in recent coreutils releases.

Answer (score 11):

If `timeout` and `doalarm` are not available (e.g., OS X) you can use `expect`:

```
timeout() {

    time=$1

    # start the command in a subshell to avoid problem with pipes
    # (spawn accepts one command)
    command="/bin/sh -c \"$2\""

    expect -c "set echo \"-noecho\"; set timeout $time; spawn -noecho $command; expect timeout { exit 1 } eof { exit 0 }"    

    if [ $? = 1 ] ; then
        echo "Timeout after ${time} seconds"
    fi

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I would have suggested but you beat me to the punch.  +1

Comment: This is great because I do actually use OSX, but at this point the command I'm using doesn't require neither piping nor actually waiting for the command to command to finish (it never will, it's a server). I'll still go with sleeping and killing, but nevertheless this will certainly help me out in the future, thanks.

Comment: P.S. I forgot how aggravating it is to be unable to upvote great answers...

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to do this manually. However, I would only do this if the options Ignacio suggests in his answer are unavailable:

```
timeout_f () {
    $1 &
    sleep $2
    kill $! # ends somecommand if still running
}

timeout_f 'somecommand --someoptions' 10 && #need 2 &'s
echo "forked.." # happens immediately
```

Comment: Actually a similar method was specified in the same FAQ entry, and I'll probably be relying on it since I don't want extra binaries hanging around. Thanks.

Comment: The forked process will always wait for the timeout. There also problems with *complex* commands: e.g., with pipes and redirection.

Comment: I'm not sure if the fork waiting for the full timeout is really significant, but I agree that if 'somecommand' is actually `this | that | etc` then the kill will not work.

Comment: I never specified the need for piping my output. This will do nicely.

Comment: If the command has already timed out by itself, this method runs the risk of killing something that has been assigned the same PID.