# Read data from a pipe for a certain amount of time (in seconds)

Tags: shell, pipe, stdout

Is there an easy way to create a pipe that only lasts for a given amount of wall time?

I want to be able to take a "snapshot" of what's being written STDOUT for a period of time (rather than bytes or lines). Something like

`tail -f /var/log/whatever.log | pipe_for_seconds 10 > ./10_second_sample_of_log`

I'm using BASH, but if this is dramatically easier in some other shell, I'd like to hear about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gnu *coreutils* since version 7.0 has a `timeout` command:

```
timeout 10 tail -f /var/log/whatever.log
```

If you *really* need a pipe to timeout for some slightly different procedure, then pipe into `timeout`:

```
tail -f /var/log/whatever.log | timeout 10 cat > ./10_second_sample_of_log
```

Note though that *killing some arbitrary part of a pipeline may cause problems due to buffering*, depending on signals and program behaviour (this question covers related issues: [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe) ). It will usually change the *exit code* of the process too.

If you don't have (a recent) coreutils, this simple timeout program also works well
  http://www.unixlabplus.com/unix-prog/timeout/timeout.html
or the perl approach:

```
tail -f /var/log/whatever.log | perl -n -e 'BEGIN{alarm 10; $|=1}; print;'
```

(Note the `$|=1` turns off output buffering, this is to prevent loss of output in the pipeline, as referred to above.)

The (slightly ancient) [Netpipes](http://web.purplefrog.com/~thoth/netpipes/netpipes.html) package also has a `timelimit` command (which you can still find on some Linux systems).

This similar question has a few more options: [How to introduce timeout for shell scripting?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43340/how-to-introduce-timeout-for-shell-scripting)

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```bash
tail -f /var/log/whatever.log > ten_second_sample & sleep 10 && kill $!
```

Launch `tail` in background and in parallel `sleep` 10 seconds **and after that** `kill` `$!` which is the PID of the last launched background process.

Answer (score 0):

Relying on killing PID may not be reliable if `tail -f` exits too soon (e.g. file does not exist).
Another more generic solution, that will also stop the "kill timer" if it is done before the timeout is to use `wait` and `kill %%` (`%%` indicates the most recent job started by bash - using `&`).

The construction will look like this (in which `sleep 2` is any custom command with parameters etc and the timeout is set to 10 seconds):

```
# Your command that may take some (or not) time to execute:
sleep 2 &
# Set a timer that kills the last started job
sleep 10 & wait -n 1; kill %%; wait -n 1
```

This construction will wait until either the timeout is reached, or the custom command is done executing (in this case the `sleep 2` will always stop first). Then, respectively the command or timeout will be killed with `kill %%`. Then, the last `wait -n 1` blocks further execution until the command or timeout is actually killed (this is optional but likely desired).

Note. Earlier commands executed in parallel will not be affected, as is required and expected.

## Example

A more practical example with reading a line from a named pipe with timeout, but for which the timeout-flag of `read` cannot be used:

```
# Custom bash function to set timeout in seconds for the most recently started job (parallel execution).
timeout() { sleep $1 & wait -n 1; kill %%; wait -n 1 }

# Example 1:
mkfifo /tmp/test
read ln </tmp/test &
timeout 10
```

Because there is nothing written to `/tmp/test` it will timeout after 10 seconds. In order to show that even when the command terminates immediately it will stop the kill timer:

```
# Example 2:
mkfifo /tmp/test
echo "Hello" >/tmp/test &
ln="$(read ln </tmp/test && echo -e "$ln" & timeout 10)"
echo "Line was read: $ln"
```

Note with regard to practical use of named pipe. Because `read ln` is executed in a subshell, it cannot be accessed in the (parent) script. Therefore, the line is printed with `echo` to store it in a (different) variable `ln`.