# I want to terminate a python script if it doesn’t output anything to the terminal in 2 min

Tags: bash, shell, python, executable

Here's my current bash which is just a loop

```
while true ; do 
     python3 /Users/Name/Desktop/pythoncode.py
done
```

I want to terminate `pythoncode.py` if it doesn’t output anything to the terminal in 2 min

Comment: Does your system provide the `timeout` command? See for example [How to introduce timeout for shell scripting?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43340/how-to-introduce-timeout-for-shell-scripting)

Comment: I have the timeout command but I want the script to run forever if it is still outputting stuff to the terminal so I cannot simply just set a timeout of 2 minutes

Comment: It's not elegant, but you could add `|tee /tmp/pythoncode_out` at the end your `python3` command, and then have another loop than checks every 15 seconds and kills the bash processes running the loop if `pythoncode_out` is more than 2 minutes old. In theory, one could write a program to do what you ask, killing python3 just like `head` kills its source process if the given conditions were met.

Comment: you might be able to nest it in the python script

Answer (score 7):

With `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/system
(
  echo $sysparam[pid]
  exec python3 /Users/Name/Desktop/pythoncode.py
) | {
  read pid
  if sysread -o 1 -s 1 -t120; then
    cat
  else
    kill -s PIPE $pid 2> /dev/null
  fi
}
```

With `bash`, you can do something similar with:

```
(
  echo "$BASHPID"
  exec python3 /Users/Name/Desktop/pythoncode.py
) | {
  read pid
  if LC_ALL=C IFS= read -rd '' -n1 -t120 byte; then
    if [ -n "$byte" ]; then
      printf %s "$byte"
    else
      printf '\0'
    fi
    cat
  else
    kill -s PIPE "$pid" 2> /dev/null
  fi
}
```

Those check whether that script writes anything to stdout, not specifically to the terminal.

If you also want to stop if the command has written something, but stopped and hasn't output anything within two minutes, or in other words, kill the command after 2 minutes of inactivity, then you could just use `socat`:

```
socat -T120 'exec:python3 /Users/Name/Desktop/pythoncode.py' -
```

Or with `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/system
(
  echo $sysparam[pid]
  exec python3 /Users/Name/Desktop/pythoncode.py
) | {
  read pid
  while
    sysread -o 1 -t 120; ret=$?
    (( ret == 0 ))
  do continue; done
  # 5 means EOF
  (( ret == 5 )) || kill $pid
}
```

Comment: Looks beautiful, but the Bash version isn't working for me (it never exits; my line 3 was `exec tail -f ...`).

Comment: Thank you Stephane

Comment: @bitinerant, see edit. I suspect you ran `tail -f` on a non-empty file, so it *did* output something initially.

Comment: Thank you for your work, Stéphane. However, on Bash 5.0, the new version exits immediately: `rm -f /tmp/watched_file; touch $_; ( echo "$BASHPID"; exec tail /tmp/watched_file; ) | { read pid; if LC_ALL=C IFS= read -rd '' -n1 -t15 byte; then if [ -n "$byte" ]; then  printf %s "$byte"; else printf '\0'; fi; cat; else kill -s PIPE "$pid" 2> /dev/null; fi; }`

Comment: @bitinerant, you missed the `-f` flag. But by *see edit*, I meant the socat part and below to handle inactivity timeout.

Comment: Ugh. You're right. However, with `exec tail -f ...`, I can't get the Bash version to work (doesn't exit). The `socat` option looks useful.

Answer (score 3):

With `bash`, you can use process substitution and redirection, and a `while` loop with `read` `-t` timeout. The subshell will be no more, when the `while` loop exits because of the timeout (That means when the python script has no output, seems inactive, for 2 minutes).

```
while IFS= read -r -t120 x; do
    printf "%s\n" "$x"
done < <(python3 script.py)
```

Note: I have assumed line-oriented output into this example (or else `read` and `printf` char by char).

---

The difference of this structure to using a pipe, is that we have one command here. When this command exits, the file input from the file descriptor is over, the command in the subshell writing into this descriptor is over. So the python script is killed *just after the timeout*.

When piping like this:

```
python3 script.py | { 
    while IFS= read -r -t120 x; do
        printf "%s\n" "$x"
    done
}
```

we execute two commands, and if the second one exits (because of the timeout), the first one will continue to run, until trying to write to the pipe again. When this happens, it will terminate, without writing anything more, because of broken pipe. So here the python script is killed *when trying to write again after the timeout*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Context: My python script sometimes freezes cuz it's internet based. If it hasn't outputted anything in 2 min it means that it is frozen and it will never output anything again. Instead of waiting for me to find out that it's frozen and restarting it, I want it to happen automatically. Correct me if I'm wrong but this would not work for my situation because: If my python hasn't outputted in 2 min it means that is frozen and it will never output anything again so the problem of it being frozen will remain forever.

Comment: You may want to read [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123)

Comment: @ArdalanGhazizadeh if the script is inactive for 2 minutes, it will be terminated.

Comment: Excellent. IMHO, your answer is better than Stephane's.

Answer (score 0):

If the acceptable accuracy is ~1 second, you could use `date +%s` to collect the actual time and check how long there's no output from your script (collecting it as a shell variable):

```bsh
ELAPSED_T=0 # the time that has passed since last output
LAST_OUT_T=`date +%s` # avoid to stop if the first iteration has empty output
while [ "$ELAPSED_T" -lt 120 ]; do # continue if the last output was printed less than 120 seconds ago
    OUT=`python3 /Users/Name/Desktop/pythoncode.py` # run the script and collect the output
    echo "$OUT" # print the output on screen

    if [ -n "$OUT" ]; then # if the output is not empty, update the last output time
        LAST_OUT_T=`date +%s`
    else # otherwise, evaluate how much time has passed since last output
        NOW_T=`date +%s`
        ELAPSED_T=$((NOW_T - LAST_OUT_T))
    fi  
done
```

Comment: The assignment to `OUT` will not finish until the Python script exits.

Comment: Correct, but I suppose that the author's script evaluates something, occasionally prints on the console, then terminates and is runed again, since the author wrapped it in an infinite loop. If @Ardalan could explain better his script behaviour we could understand better.

Comment: The issue seems to be that the Python script needs to be killed if it doesn't output anything during a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the GNU `timeout` command. It takes the duration as an argument followed by the command. Here is a simple invocation:

`timeout 5s ping www.website.com`

From its manpage:

```
TIMEOUT(1)                                                                          User Commands                                                                         TIMEOUT(1)

NAME
       timeout - run a command with a time limit

SYNOPSIS
       timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...
       timeout [OPTION]

DESCRIPTION
       Start COMMAND, and kill it if still running after DURATION.
...
```

You can also specify the type of signal to send to the process (like HUP, 9, SIGTERM, etc.) at the end of the timeout.

HTH.