# Timeout doesn't occur when reading from fifo using `read`

Tags: shell, timeout

Look at this code:

```
while read -t 3 line; do
    echo ${line}
done < /opt/data.log
```

`data.log` is a fifo. One process is writing to this, and this code should be reading it to show to the user. But I want it to exit when there is no more data in the fifo for 3 seconds.

The problem is it never times out. I write to this fifo, it shows me:

```
read: 6: Illegal option -t
```

What is wrong?

**[UPDATE]**

Yes, I was using `/bin/sh` as a shebang which is a symbolic link to `dash`. I changed it to `/bin/bash`. but it does not make any benefit. It waits for ever if no one opens the fifo. I want a timeout solution that works when the other end of the fifo has not opened it.

Comment: Perhaps useful: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10698/timing-out-in-a-shell-script But if you don't have stringent portability requirements like I did, using bash is a lot simpler

Comment: The timeout isn't happening because the `read` isn't executing yet. The redirection has to open the FIFO before the loop can start, and the open is blocking. You need a timeout on the redirection operator. I can't think of a good way to do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did find a good way to do this:

```
exec 5<>/opt/data.log

while read -7 3 line <& 5; do
    echo ${line}
done
```

I open it for read and write so the script does not block for ever. here is the descriptin:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4875924/654269

Comment: Very useful, thanks.  Minor typo - `read -7 3` should be `read -t 3`, right?

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this and yes, @JamesFerguson, it appears to be a typo. I have `-t` working in `ash`.

Answer (score 4):

are you using bash?  or some other sh?  `read -t` is a kshism (also supported by bash and zsh but not standard)

It works in bash, but not in dash:

```
$ bash -c 'echo foo | while read -t 3 xxxx ; do echo $xxxx ; done'
foo
```

```
$ dash -c 'echo foo | while read -t 3 xxxx ; do echo $xxxx ; done'
dash: 1: read: Illegal option -t
```

Comment: yes. I'm using bash in debian 6.0.5

Comment: I think you're using dash or some other minimalist sh.

Comment: @MajidAzimi what's your shebang line? If it is `#!/bin/sh` you are not using bash but `dash`

Comment: your are right, I was using `dash`. but it doesn't make any difference. see the update.