# Cancel a command in AND

Tags: bash

When I execute `A & B` and then cancel with `^C` only B gets killed, and A runs on the background. How can I execute `A & B` as **one** command I can kill without killing the background job ?

Comment: Perhaps you should specify what *behavior* you want when you say "execute `A & B` as 'one command.'"  Do you mean you want them to execute sequentially rather than concurrently?  To have the same PID (which is impossible)?  To have one be a child of the other?  To have one die when the other is killed?  "One command" is quite vague; A and B are separate *simple* commands however you connect them (whether in a pipeline, a list, a compound command, or other method.)

Comment: from http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204480/run-multiple-commands-and-kill-them-as-one-in-bash
    `~$ trap 'kill %1; kill %2' SIGINT`;
    `~$ command1 & command2 & command3`

Comment: They should run both simultanuously. And one has to die when the other is killed

Answer (score 2):

The solution : Run it as `(A & B)` with parentheses