# How to move a process from one process group to another, and how to list the processes in each process group?

Tags: shell, process, process-groups

Based on what I have learned so far, a terminal has only one session, and a session has one or more process groups, and a process group has one or more processes.

The following image illustrates this:

[image]

I have two questions:

1. How to move a process from one process group to another?
2. How to list the processes in each process group?

---

**Edit:** I mean how to do these two things from the terminal and not programmatically.

Comment: This seems like several questions (and "the terminal" would use the exact same system calls that a program would, as it uses the same API)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a user's or even a typical programmer's perspective, you don't move processes from one group to another. Organizing process groups is the job of the shell. When you run a job interactively, the shell puts it in its own group. The primary intent of doing that is to kill the whole group (e.g. all the processes in a pipeline) when the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

More generally, the one thing that is made possible by process groups is to atomically kill a set of processes. If you try to list some processes and then kill them, one of them may have forked in between. When you kill a process group, that kills all the processes in the group, even if they're busy forking.

The one thing you may sometimes want to do as a user or application programmer is to run a new process in its own group. There's no user-level command to do just that. You can do it by starting an interactive shell. (See [Timing out in a shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10698/timing-out-in-a-shell-script) for a complex example.) There are other commands such as the [`timeout` utility](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#timeout-invocation) from GNU coreutils and the Linux and the [`setsid` utility](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setsid.1.html) from the util-linux suite that create a new process group as part of their oepration.

The system call to move a process to a different process group is [`setpgid`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setpgid.html). (There's also a partial alias called `setpgrp`.) There are restrictions: it may only be called by the process itself or its parent, and the target group must be in the same session as the original group. You can't arbitrarily move a process from one group to another.

There's no specific way to enumerate the processes in a group. All you can do is enumerate all the processes and select the ones in that specific group. You can list process groups in the `ps` output by including the `pgid` column (e.g. `ps -e -o pid,ppid,pgid,args`).