# How to redirect a command's `stdin` as well as `stdout` to the output

Tags: pipe, stdout, stdin, tee

Suppose I have the Python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
input('Y/n: ')
print('Next line')
```

After I press `Y`, I want both the terminal and my `output.txt` containing:

```
Y/n: Y
Next line
```

Running the following I don't get `Y` in the output:

```
$ python ask.py 2>&1 | tee output.txt
```

How can I include my response in the output?

Comment: @Quasímodo Well my real script is a lot more complicated, uses the `logging` module, `input()` and `print()`. I'm trying to modify that currently, if there just isn't a simple Linux solution. But a simple Linux solution is much preferred over modifying my Python script. What if say the Python script is a system script that I can't modify.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Along the lines of what you already have (tested with `python3`):

```bsh
tee -a output.txt | python ask.py 2>&1 | tee -a output.txt
```

As a downside, you will need to explicitly type something after the python script terminates, to make the first `tee` attempt writing to the pipe, receive a `SIGPIPE` and exit. You may be able to overcome this limitation with:

```bsh
tee -a output.txt | { python ask.py 2>&1; kill 0; } | tee -a output.txt
```

Where `kill` is used to kill all the processes in the current process group (i.e. the dedicated process group the pipeline is run as). (But note that [caveats may apply](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18711/315749)).

An alternative, if `script` is available to you, may be:

```bsh
script -q -c 'python ask.py' output.txt
```

In this case `python` will be connected to a pseudo-terminal device, ensuring it behaves as if it were run interactively on a terminal.