# how exec command is user interactive shell script to redirect all output/input/error to a file

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection

I have mentioned below cmd on top of the script

```
exec > >(tee -a "$log_file") 2>&1
# (all remaining script part here)
```

The shell script is user interactive, so I want the inputs given by user are also to be redirected in same file. How this can be achieved?

Comment: The user input goes into the commands reading the input, not into the log file. If you want to capture the whole session, run it with the `script` utility.

Comment: can you show with example please

Comment: Install the `script` utility, if it's not already installed, then run `script -c ./myshellscript.sh` (where `myshellscript.sh` is the name of your script). You would not need the `exec` command in the script.

Comment: Similar, but placing input/output redirections outside the script: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/639326/315749 (plus a `script` example).